# Do Iraqi citizens holding green card need a visa to re enter USA from Iraq?

Tags: visas

Im Iraqi citizen  holding a green card ,living in USA now.
I want to visit my relatives in Iraq and stay there for a month.
Do I need a visa to re-enter the USA when coming back from Iraq please?!

Comment: No you don't.  Changes to the visa waiver program do not affect you because you do not use the visa waiver program.